# how to loop in methods for wrong user input in methods

Tags: java, variables, methods

How do I make a java method that accepts only positive integer and if user enters negative integer then it re-prompts to enter from main method or go back to main method to input... This was all that I was able to figure out:

```
  public class error5
{
public void error5(int quantity){
   if (quantity <=0){
       System.out.println("**Error5**- Quantity on hand is negative value");
       System.out.print("Enter quantity on hand: ");
       break;
    }
   else {
       System.out.print("");
       break;
    }
 }
}
```

What to do next?

Comment: use a 'do while' loop.

Comment: can u just code for me as am beginner

Comment: This is not a site for asking other people to write your code for you.

Comment: google around, dont ask for code. Ask for ideas and direction only, implement your own code.

Comment: i got the method to use do while loop after that how can i make user to reinput for positive integer

Comment: you can't use break statement without loop.

Comment: I've downvoted, to discourage requests like 'code it for me'. This site is not a free programmer resource.

Answer (score 1):

You will just need to convert the `if` to `while`

```
while(quantity <=0){
       System.out.println("**Error5**- Quantity on hand is negative value");
       System.out.print("Enter quantity on hand: ");
       //and accept the new value here
    }
```

**Update** You will need to do something like this. Pseudo code:

```
while(1){
Take the user input quantity
if quantity>0 continue;
else
print "please input a positive value"
}
```

**Update 2**
If you wanna make it shorter then do:

```
int quantity=-2
while(quantity<0){
take user input
if(quantity<0)  print"enter greater value"}
```

Comment: your answer is fine, +1 if it can compensate the anonymous downvoter's activity

Comment: yeah i got the method now how can make user to re input positive integer

Comment: By simple replacement of while to if is not good idea. Plz checkout my answer.. below.

Comment: yes but how can i reprompt the user to input positive value

Comment: plz check my answer to know...its posted now

Comment: i know that code but can u please say me what to do next how can i reprompt for input

Comment: @user3591952 Kindly keep on deleting un-useful comments once their purpose is finished because it should be presentable and short, precise for some other person to read it later

Comment: can u please tell me how to reprompt for input and it is method not main

Comment: @user3591952 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769024/in-java-how-can-i-take-a-variable-obtained-from-a-user-input-from-one-method-an once, in there it is shown how to take input from user, check it try to code it yourself if you get an error (search for answer on google but if you cannot find it) put the code here and then tell what is the error and then we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

By simple replacement of `while` to `if` is not good idea. what you can do is put `if` statement to check for negative value, and in else part you can do what you ought to do with positive value.

```
if(quantity <= 0){
System.out.println("**Error5**- Quantity on hand is negative value");
System.out.print("Enter quantity on hand: ");
}else{
System.out.print("");
//Do Something with Positive value
}
```

No need to have break statements because `if`..`else` statement will do the work by evaluating condition. If condition evaluates true than it will execute code in `if` block otherwise `else` block will be executed.

**Update:**

This will only be used for taking input once, and checking and re-prompting user. For looping you need to use `do`..`while` or `while` loop.

Comment: And if the user inputs a negative value twice? or maybe more times then? Therefore it is better to put it in a loop, see my update

Comment: @DakshShah Ok I see the part where Question is about Loop...!!!! your answer justifies the question

Comment: i know that code but can u please say me what to do next how can i reprompt for input

Comment: but according to java script i cannot use prompt for user input in method

Comment: @user3591952 you are mixing Java with Java Script..!!!! If you are using Java as shown in mine and Daksh's answer... you are re-prompting user for input when quantity is 0 or negative

Comment: i compiled and its just printing is not prompting for userinput

Comment: @user3591952 you can use one of the way like Scanner or inputstream to read user output.... Because System.out.println is used for only printing out to user not for getting input from user. You can google around for it. It is pretty easy to find and understand

Comment: can i use scanner input in java methods

Comment: For Getting input from User Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287538/how-to-get-basic-user-input-for-java

Comment: Hi @JavaRocks. I've edited your post to improve case issues, and to add some `inline formatting`. We're not too keen on all-caps sections here, so if you could take care with your answers, it will save editors future work. Thanks!